# TypeError: dropna() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop a list of columns that are in `df`

```
cols = df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
df = df.dropna([cols], axis = 1)
```

But I get the error

> TypeError: dropna() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Any ideas how I can drop the list in cols ?

Comment: The api for this has changed. It used to be as you have it above, but now it's `df = df.dropna(subset=cols)`. If you include `subset=` and leave out `axis=1` you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.notna().all()]
#alternative with iverting mask by ~
#df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.isna().any()]
#alternative 1
#df1 = df.dropna(axis=1)
```

For your solution need `drop` with omit list `[]` for remove columns:

```
cols = df.columns[df.isna().any()]
df1 = df.drop(cols, axis = 1)
print (df1)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think the function is .notnull() and .isnull() instead of notna() and isna().

Comment: @ManishSaraswat - This is in new version of pandas - [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks for it (: